# Installing imagemagick in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick

So I am trying to install imagemagick on Windows. There seem to be no way to make it run. I am using PHP 5.6.20.

I have installed imagemagick 7.0.1 in `C:\

Then included the imagemagick dll in the extension folder from xampp.

There are no errors when I run Apache.

There are the following entries in phpinfo:

Enviroment path:

```
C:\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.1-
```

PHP Variables:

```
*_SERVER["PATH"]    C:\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.1-*
```

When I try to run the code, however, it says that the class imagick doesnt exist.

Here is the code:

```
$im = new imagick( 'a.jpg' );

// resize by 200 width and keep the ratio

$im->thumbnailImage( 200, 0);

// write to disk

$im->writeImage( 'a_thumbnail.jpg' );
```

Comment: You need to double quote PATH entries with spaces in such as `"C:\Program Files\..."`

Comment: The PATH is automaticly added to phpinfo I cannot change anything there.

Comment: Run a `phpInfo()` to see if it is installed correctly. Imagick should be listed with the supported extensions.

Comment: You have installed Imagemagick ( which you are checking for ) and are trying to use Imagick.